# Call to undefined method Vendormodel::read()

Tags: codeigniter

I have created a controller named as export for making export to excel function but this error is coming.

Not getting anything. New to CI.

```
    $this->load->model('vendormodel');
    $vendor = new vendormodel();
    $vendor->table ='vendor';
    $data['vendor'] = $vendor->read();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the `models/Vendormodel.php` there is a public method `read();`. For example,

```
class Vendormodel extends CI_Model {

    public $table = NULL;

    public function read() 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And it is better to write like this:

`$vendor = new Vendormodel()`;

And even better:

```
$this->load->model('vendormodel');
$this->vendormodel->table = 'vendor';
$data['vendor'] = $this->vendormodel->read();
```

Comment: Okay, will do it.